# check service state with handler in onResume

Tags: android

I created a service for a long running background task. It is implemented with a HandlerThread. (example below)

For the application it is important, that a new task can only be started, when the previous task was finished.

A broadcast is sent to the activity, when a task is finished. Only then the user can start a new task.

That works fine so far, except when the activity goes to the background. The broadcastReceiver is unregistered in onPause. If the broadcast is sent before the next onResume of the activity, the message is lost. But in onResume we have to find out, if there is an unfinished task.

Is there a reliable way to find out if the service is still busy?

```
public class LongRunningService extends Service {

    private HandlerThread thread;

    private LongRunningServiceHandler longRunningServiceHandler;

    private class LongRunningServiceHandler extends Handler {

        public LongRunningServiceHandler(Looper l) {
            super(l);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            switch (msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
            }

            final Intent i = new Intent(LongRunningService.class.getName());
            i.putExtra("STATUS", "finished");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(LongRunningService.this).sendBroadcast(i);
        }
    }

    public LongRunningService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        this.thread = new HandlerThread("UDPHandler", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        this.thread.start();
        this.longRunningServiceHandler = new LongRunningServiceHandler(this.thread.getLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        final Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = 1;
        this.longRunningServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes: bind (`Contxt#bindService`) to that service and ask it if its busy or not - more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

Comment: You can either bind the service OR Register/unregister Broadcast in `onCreate/onDestroy`.